# multiple filters on ICollectionView with multiple condition checks WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, icollectionview

This question has been asked before in different forms, but none answer my question. I have scraped this forum and Windows dev forum for info, before posting this. I cannot make sense of how to accomplish this task.

I am at my wits end.

I have a DataGrid that is binded to an ICollectionView. This data was pulled via a stored procedure and the DataGrid is automatically generated based on the columns in each table. For reference, the SP returns a list of objects, each with a series of members like stock_symbol, stock_price, Date etc.

There are a series of filters I would like to apply to this collection view. Two comboboxes and two datepickers, to be more specific. Each with a checkbox to signify they are active.

Each checkbox event handler stores the data that was selected from the combobox or the datepicker. I am trying to compare what is in those variables, to each relevant member of the object list and send that filtered object list back to the DataGrid.

This is my code:

```
private void FillDataGrid()
    {
        //Connect contains a simple stored procedure connection to SQL server
        var Client = Connect();
        DTOClass[] dTOs = Client.GetData();
        SetDTOClass(dTOs);

        MainGrid.ItemsSource = FilterView(dTOs);
    }
```

Here is FilterView() (apologies for the long commented sections, I am trying to include my attempts in one foul sweep):

```
 public ICollectionView /*List<DTOClass>*/ FilterView(DTOClass[] DTO)
    {
        if (_CollectionViewInternal == null)
        {
            //Assign collected DTO object to an ICollectionView
            _CollectionViewInternal = 
       CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DTO);
        }

        /*
        ObservableCollection<DTOClass> DTOview = null;

        if (DTOViewInternal == null)
        {
            int j = DTO.Length;
            DTOview = new ObservableCollection<DTOClass>();
            for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
            {
                DTOview.Add(DTO[i]);
            }
            DTOViewInternal = DTOview;
        }
        */

        //Add a default sort description to the Date column
        _CollectionViewInternal.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Date", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

        //assign our view to the maingrid (move this to later in the 
        //MainGrid.ItemsSource = _CollectionViewInternal;

        if (MainGrid.ItemsSource != null)
        {

            /*List<Predicate<IEnumerable<DTOClass[]>>>*/ FilteredView = new List<Predicate<IEnumerable<DTOClass[]>>>();

            //DateTime _zeroDay = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            //DateTime _now = DateTime.Now;

            FilteredView.Clear();


            return FilteredView = _CollectionViewInternal.Where(Function(w) w.accountname.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
                            Or w.firstname.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
                            Or w.lastname.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
                            Or w.isenabled.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
                            Or w.description.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
                            Or w.lastlogontimestamp.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
                            Or w.whencreated.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
                            Or w.whenchanged.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
                            Or w.oulocation.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
                            Or w.co.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
                            Or w.l.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
                            Or w.state.Contains(txtFilter.Text))


            //if (yearsChosen > 0)
            /* Stock, Maxadj, FromDate, ToDate */
            /*
            if (Stock_CheckBox.IsChecked != null)
            {

                FilteredView.Add(new Predicate<IEnumerable<DTOClass[]>>(x => x.Where(item => item. == Stock_ComboBoxText)));
            }

            if (letterChosen != "Any")
            {
                FilteredView.Add(new Predicate<IEnumerable<DTOClass[]>>(x => x.LastName.StartsWith(letterChosen)));
            }
            if (genderChosen != "Any")
            {
                FilteredView.Add(new Predicate<IEnumerable<DTOClass[]>>(x => x.Gender.Equals(genderChosen.Substring(0, 1))));
            }

            _CollectionViewInternal.Filter = dynamic_Filter;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PeopleView");
            // Bring the current person back into view in case it moved
            if (CurrentPerson != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<DTOClass[]> current = CurrentPerson;
                _CollectionViewInternal.MoveCurrentToFirst();
                _CollectionViewInternal.MoveCurrentTo(current);
            }
            */


            /*
            if (DTOview == null)
            {
                DTOview = DTOViewInternal;
            } else
            {
                DTOViewInternal.
            }
            */


            //var collection = DTO;
            //var symbol = collection.Where(item => item.Date == ).ToList();

            //DTOview = new ObservableCollection<DTOClass>();
            //IEnumerable<DTOClass> DTOview2;
            //List<IEnumerable<DTOClass>> FilteredView = new List<IEnumerable<DTOClass>>();

            /*
            if (Stock_ComboBoxText != null)
            {
                //var collection = DTO;
                var collection = DTO.Where(item => item.stock_symbol == Stock_ComboBoxText).Cast<DTOClass>().ToList();
                //DTOview.Add(filtered.Cast<DTOClass>());
                //FilteredView.Add(collection.Cast<DTOClass>());
                FilteredView.Add(collection);
                MainGrid.ItemsSource = FilteredView[0];
                //FilteredView = filtered.Cast<DTOClass>();

            }
            if (Maxadj_ComboBoxText != 0)
            {
                var collection = DTO.Where(item => item.stock_price_adj_close == Maxadj_ComboBoxText).Cast<DTOClass>().ToList();
                FilteredView.Add(collection);
                MainGrid.ItemsSource = FilteredView[0];

                //DTOview.Add(DTO.Where(item => item.stock_price_adj_close == ).ToList());
            }
            if (From_DatePickValue != null)
            {
                var collection = DTO.Where(item => item.Date >= From_DatePickValue).Cast<DTOClass>().ToList();
                FilteredView.Add(collection);
                MainGrid.ItemsSource = FilteredView[0];

            }
            if (To_DatePickValue != null)
            {
                var collection = DTO.Where(item => item.Date <= To_DatePickValue).Cast<DTOClass>().ToList();
                FilteredView.Add(collection);
                MainGrid.ItemsSource = FilteredView[0];

            }
            */





            //DTOview = DTOViewInternal;
            //DTOview = null;
            //DTOClass[] dto = GetDTOClass();

            //ListCollectionView collectionView = new ListCollectionView(DTOViewInternal);


            /*
            collectionView.Filter = (e) =>
            {
            //int j = DTO.Length;
            DTOClass[] dtofiltered = e as DTOClass[];


            //for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
            //{

                if ((Stock_ComboBoxText != null) && (DTOview[0][i].stock_symbol == Stock_ComboBoxText))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if ((Maxadj_ComboBoxText != 0) && (DTOview[0][i].stock_price_adj_close == Maxadj_ComboBoxText))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if ((From_DatePickValue != null) && (DTOview[0][i].Date >= From_DatePickValue))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if ((To_DatePickValue != null) && (DTOview[0][i].Date <= To_DatePickValue))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return true;
        };
        */

            //return collectionView.Cast<DTOClass>().ToList();
            //return collectionView.Filter;
            //return null;
            //MainGrid.ItemsSource = null;
            //MainGrid.ItemsSource = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collectionView.ToString());

        }
        else
        {
            //MainGrid.ItemsSource = DTOview[0].ToList();
            //MainGrid.ItemsSource = DTOview;
            //return DTOview[0].ToList();

            return _CollectionViewInternal;
        }
        return _CollectionViewInternal;
    }
```

I only want to filter on a column, if it's relevant checkbox is checked. This is easy pickings with one filter, but more than one is proving to be beyond challenging.

As you can see I have attempted numerous solutions. I have tried using an ObservableCollection, I have tried filtering the object list directly and then adding it to an ICollectionView. Nothing works.

I have been attempting to graft this example: [Complicated Filtering ICollectionView](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26673.wpf-collectionview-tips.aspx#Complicated_Filtering). But I cannot make heads or tails of it. I still don't understand predicates and tbh I really can't wrap my head around how it works.

I know it's frowned upon to ask 'gimme the code' questions. But if someone could just see past that and point out what I am doing wrong here, maybe even give me the code, I would be very grateful. I have spent weeks trying to understand this and I have run out of time on this assignment.

If not, then that's cool but please refrain from commenting on this thread. Don't take pride in withholding the answer either, I am usually an embedded C programmer and I just finished a full-sized OSX-Windows port for a massive Adobe AfterFX plugin. So I don't need snide remarks or any nonsense about putting more effort into learning, I just want to finish this assignment and be done with it.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: @elgonzo edited for your convenience. If you would like to contribute then by all means, I am willing to hear your answer.

Comment: I cannot really provide an answer as i do not know how you want to make your filter logic. But it shouldn't be too difficult to implement. You might try using the CollectionView.Filter predicate (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter(v=vs.110).aspx). It is just a delegate of a function that receives an element from the CollectionView and returns true or false, indicating whether that element should be filtered or not. The CollectionView will call this function for each individual element to determine if this element is filtered or not. (contd.)

Comment: An alternative approach (but essentially very similar), is using the CollectionViewSource.Filter event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) to filter elements. An event handler for this event essentially functions as the filter method. Since an event handler cannot return a true/false condition, the `Accepted` field of the eventargs argument of this event would be set (thus functioning as some kind of return value). Otherwise it pretty much would be the same as the CollectionView.Filter predicate i mentioned above (contd.)

Comment: Whether to use CollectionView.Filter predicate or the CollectionViewSource.Filter event depends. It could be that you want to use the same CollectionViewSource in a different view. Having the filtering on the CVS level would apply the filtering to all views using this CVS. If you want different filtering in the views using the CVS, go with the CollectionView.Filter predicate... (contd)

Comment: Finally, aside from realizing the filter method (which would use the values of the UI elements specifying the filtering), you will need to tell the CollectionView to reapply the filter whenever the value of a UI element related to the filtering changed. You can do this by invoking the CollectionView.Refresh() method. (...the end...) Sorry for not being able to give an exhaustive answer, but hopefully these pointers help you to proceed.

Comment: "It is just a delegate of a function that receives an element from the CollectionView and returns true or false, indicating whether that element should be filtered or not" 

yeh so I've tried that so many times in so many different ways:

_CollectionViewInternal.Filter(DTO.stock_symbol == Stock_ComboBoxText);

or 

                    FilteredView.Add(new Predicate<IEnumerable<DTOClass[]>>(x => x.Where(item => item.stock_symbol == Stock_ComboBoxText)));

neither of those worked because Stock_ComboBoxText doesn't exist in that context and stock_symbol isn't a property of those objects

Comment: Thank you. I won't lie. None of that makes any sense. 

All I am trying to do is filter rows with values that correspond to the stored values from two comboxes and two datepickers, but only if the checkbox of the combobox or datepicker is checked. Just like an SQL filter, honestly given that a datagrid is used for what I can only assume to be a wide collection of very similar tasks that would inevitably require this functionality, I am surprised it's this difficult.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with predicates/delegate or filtering in particular. It is a problem of lacking basic understanding of scopes in C#. Essentially, from your previous comment i would think your real question/problem boils down to "How can i access some member/field/variable declared in some class/method in another class/method", right?

Comment: I understand C# just fine. I have programmed extensively in Unity3D. My problem is WPF as a whole. It's just filtering some rows man, shouldn't need a degree in quantum physics to get it... anyway I've wasted enough of your time. Thanks anyway

Comment: One way to do this is with a list of predicates and use linq trueforall. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26673.wpf-collectionview-tips.aspx#Complicated_Filtering

Comment: Hey @Andy. Thanks for commenting here mate. Unfortunately, I have already been following that page's instructions with great intent. I'll post my attempt below

Answer (score 0):

Code to complement above comment:

```
List<Predicate<IEnumerable<DTOClass[]>>> FilteredView = null;

 public ICollectionView FilterView(DTOClass[] DTO)
 {
    List<Predicate<IEnumerable<DTOClass[]>>>FilteredView = new 
    List<Predicate<IEnumerable<DTOClass[]>>>();

    FilteredView.Clear();

    if (Stock_CheckBox.IsChecked != null)
    {

    FilteredView.Add(new Predicate<IEnumerable<DTOClass[]>>(x => x.Where(item => item.stock_symbol == Stock_ComboBoxText)));
    }
}
```

I can't even get the first predicate working. Apparently .stock_symbol isn't there and I can't index item. I suppose my real question here is how do I access the stock_symbol member?

Apologies for taking so long to get there, I am extremely sleep deprived.

**EDIT:**

Dumb mistakes are made with no sleep.

```
 List<Predicate<DTOClass>> FilteredView = new List<Predicate<DTOClass>>();

            if (Stock_CheckBox.IsChecked != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < DTO.Length; i++)
                {
                    FilteredView.Add(new Predicate<DTOClass>(x => x.stock_symbol == _Stock_ComboBoxText));
                    //FilteredView.Add(new Predicate<DTOClass[]>>(x => x.stock_symbol == _Stock_ComboBoxText));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Oh wow I feel so stupid. My problem now seems obvious. I was creating a list of predicate object lists, rather than a list of predicates. No wonder I couldn't access my members. I'll keep plugging at this and update this answer with more info as I go.